# Erro ao conectar no MySql usando EF6

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Estou recebendo o erro

> 'System.Data.StrongTypingException: The value for column 'IsPrimaryKey' in table 'TableDetails' is DBNull

Sempre que tento conectar a um banco de dados MySql usando Entity Framework 6.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma dica pra corrigir?

Comment: relacionado: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961646/ef6-mysql-strongtypingexception-when-column-is-not-pk ou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575109/mysql-entity-the-value-for-column-isprimarykey-in-table-tabledetails-is

Comment: nesses links ensinam a usar os códigos `use <<database name>>
   set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';` o que eles significam?

Comment: entendi sim. eu quero saber o que esses comandos significam. qual a função deles?

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79163 acredito ser um bug na versão do MySQL pelo que eu vi na resposta, se já fez a atribuição do comando? os comandos solucionam o problema não dizem por que tem que ser feito isso, desculpa link do SoEn só repliquei.

Comment: funcionou sim. obrigado

Comment: se quiser escrever a resposta pra eu poder dar a pontuação, fique à vontade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com os links que Virgilio Novic me passou, consegui resolver assim:

Pare o serviço MySql;

Inicie novamente o serviço MySql;

Execute o seguinte comando:

```
use NOME_TABELA;
set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';
```